# how to get sum of the equation C++

Tags: c++

I am  struggling to fix this equation

[image]

First, I try to implement the second part of the equation and I got the result but the first part did not understand how to do it in the right way

here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ccomplex>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double e = M_E;
    double st = 1.0/2.0*(e + (1.0/e));
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    //std::cout << e << std::endl;

    int n ;
    double a = 1.0;
    float sum = 0.0;
    double fact =1;
    for (int i = 1;i<=n;++i ){
        fact *=i;
    }

    for (n =0; n<=st  ; n++){
        a *= 1.0/ (2 * n)*fact;
        sum += a;
    }

    std::cout << "second equation " << sum << std::endl;




    return 0;

}
```

the output

```
1.54308
second equation inf
```

the result of both equations should be nearly;

Comment: what is the value of `n` for the first loop? it seems undefined... don't you get a warning? And why are reusing it in the second loop? And why are you comparing it with the `double st`??

Comment: `1.0/ (2 * n)*fact` will evaluate as `(1.0/ (2 * n)) * fact`. You need some parens

Comment: @scohe001 that expression is completely broken anyway, it's supposed to be a factorial of `2*n` in the denominator.

Comment: Also... most importantly, how are you planning to do infinite additions? And calculate `(2n)!` for very large numbers.... I'm not sure why you are trying to implement this, but not all mathematics can or should be implemented as a calculation...

Comment: @JHBonarius you don't need infinite additions when precision is limited.

Comment: @bereal yeah, I know. There are much better solutions. But what the OP is trying to do is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

There is 4 major problems with your code:

1. uninitialized `n`
2. `st` in second loop
3. you calculate common factorial for every loop iteration
4. a large number of wrongly used arithmetic operations and variables

If you fix this error, your code will work, but ugh...

```
int main() {
    double e = M_E;
    double st = 1.0/2.0*(e + (1.0/e));
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    //std::cout << e << std::endl;

    int n = 10;
    double sum = 0.0;
    unsigned long long fact =1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        fact *= 2*i*(2*i-1);
        sum += 1.0 / fact;
    }

    std::cout << "second equation " << sum << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, i think the main mistake that I had in understanding the equation, Because of my poor understanding of mathematics.

Comment: @abl This is one of the Mclorene series for hyperbolic cosine